# chrome extension BackgroundPage how to open url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, background

I am using

`var BG = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();`

to create a Backgroundpage and I want to open a url with it and then scrape this site by using something like:

```
let product_list = document.querySelectorAll('[role="tgk"]').forEach(function (el){
```

Answer (score 0):

its impossible, you need to use requests